# Clean(er) way of inserting missing values based on multiple factors (pandas)

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, missing-data

I have a data set that consists of unique identifiers during certain months of the year, across many years. Within any particular week there are missing values for each of the unique IDs that I want to fill in with the average value for that ID for that week for that year.

I've come up with what I think is a solution, but I'm not 100% sure it's behaving how I want it to, so I'm wondering if there is a cleaner solution.

A simplified example:

```
data = [['2010-01-01', 'A', 2], ['2010-01-02', 'A', 3], ['2010-01-05', 'A', 8], 
        ['2010-01-10', 'A', 7], ['2010-01-13', 'A', 3], ['2010-01-01', 'B', 5], 
        ['2010-01-03', 'B', 2], ['2010-01-04', 'B', 1], ['2010-01-11', 'B', 7], 
        ['2010-01-14', 'B', 3], ['2011-01-01', 'A', 2], ['2011-01-02', 'A', 3], 
        ['2011-01-05', 'A', 8], ['2011-01-10', 'A', 7], ['2011-01-13', 'A', 3], 
        ['2011-01-01', 'B', 5], ['2011-01-03', 'B', 2], ['2011-01-04', 'B', 1], 
        ['2011-01-11', 'B', 7],
       ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date', 'ID', 'Score'])
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

#Insert NA values on days where there is no data for each ID
df.sort_values(by=['Date', 'ID'], inplace=True)
df = pd.concat([df[df.Date.dt.year == year].set_index('Date').\
                groupby('ID').resample('D').reset_index()
                for year in [2010, 2011]
                ]
               )

#Replace NA values with average for that ID, for that year, for that week
temp = df.groupby(['ID', df.Date.dt.year, df.Date.dt.week])\
         .transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))

df.Score = temp.Score
```

A few questions:

1. Simply put, is there a less convoluted way to do this? I don't like having to resort to a for-loop in the first step of this, but since the years are not continuous I haven't figured out a better way to tell it to not put in values after the last row of data.
2. For the "temp", I'm not clear why the groupby indexes are lost. I.E.:

   ```
   In [11]: temp.head()
   Out[11]: 
      Score
   0    2.0
   1    3.0
   2    2.5
   3    7.5
   4    8.0
   ```

Is there some way to retain the ID and Date columns? Can I trust that temp will have the same order as df, so that I can do what I'm doing (i.e.  `df.Score = temp.Score`)

Comment: For transform line, you need to set it to a column: `df['NewScore'] = df.groupby(['ID', df.Date.dt.year, df.Date.dt.week]).transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))`